# What's shutil.copytree's behavior when it encounters an error?

Tags: python, python-2.7, shutil

I'm just wondering what's the behavior for python2.7 shutil's copytree function when it encounters a file error, either let it being file unreadable, file corrupted or permission problem. I checked the documentation and its not specifying how it will behave other than raising an error. But I need to know after raising that error (and assuming it was caught), will it continue with the remaining files? If not, is there a way to specify the function so that it will behave that way?

I know I could just use `copy2` recursively but I really don't want to reinvent the wheel unless necessary.

Comment: ["*If exception(s) occur, an Error is raised with a list of reasons.*"](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree). I'm not sure how to misunderstand that. If an error is detected, copying stops right where it was.

Comment: @dhke: How's it going to run into multiple exceptions if it stops after the first one?

Comment: @Ben: Are you asking about copytree or copy2?

Comment: @user2357112 actually copytree. I was thinking about copytree recursively calling copy2 to copy the files. Thanks for pointing that out and I've edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `shutil.copytree` encounters an exception, it catches the exception, records it, and keeps going. At the end, it raises a `shutil.Error` with a list of problem conditions that occurred.

This is not well documented, but it is visible in the [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/shutil.py#L159). It is also somewhat implied by the documentation line "If exception(s) occur, an Error is raised with a list of reasons.", which implies that the function can encounter multiple exceptions.

---

As for `shutil.copy2`, that only copies one file, and there's no way it could reasonably continue if copying that file fails. If it can't copy a file, it raises an error. The file may be left half-copied if this happens.

Comment: That was very helpful and exactly what I wanted to know. Thank you!